# Efficiently multiplying tensor elements in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a Tensor in Keras with the following shape

```
x = (None, 14, 14, 32)
```

This is the weight of the convolution layer from my network.

I need to multiply elements of the tensor with each other i.e. self multiplication and then sum all the values together.

Let us consider a simpler example, if I have the following tensor

```
x = Tensor([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
```

Then I need to compute x*x and the output should be

```
1*4 + 1*5 + 1*6 + 2*4 + 2*5 + 2*6 + 3*4 + 3*5 + 3*6
```

As a naive implementation, I tried the following

```
        flattened_unpacked = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(tf.gather(x,0), [-1]))
        list1 = []
        list2 = []
        for elem in flattened_unpacked:
            list1.append(elem)
            list2.append(elem)       
        res = [i * j for j in list1 for i in list2]  
        sum_res = sum(res)
```

But it quickly ran out of memory on Google Colab. Is there an efficient way to perform this multiplication ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `broadcast_to` to make your array size compatible for matrix multiplication. See the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/broadcast_to).

Looking at the example given you are trying to do a matrix multiplication od these two matrices.
**Matrix 1: shape 3x3**

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```

**Matrix 2: shape 3x1**

```
array([[4],
       [5],
       [6]])
```

And calculate the sum of the resultant 3 x 1 matrix.

This can be achieved by:
**Step 1: Matrix multiplication:**

```
x = tf.matmul(tf.broadcast_to(tf.constant([[1], [2], [3]]), shape = (3,3)), tf.constant([[4], [5], [6]]))
```

**Output:**

```
array([[15],
       [30],
       [45]])
```

**Step 2: Adding the elements**

```
tf.reduce_sum(x)
```

**Output:**

```
90
```